# C# ASMX Service throwing The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type error

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have added a  `ASMX` service reference to my project by doing right click on the root --> add service reference.

I have it like this on my `web.config` file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="xxx" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="serviceaddress"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="xxx"
        contract="xxx" name="xxx" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This service has a method that receives a `string` with a username and validates if it exists.

The problem is that I'm testing it on `Postman` and it's returning the following error message:

```
The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type
```

I've already checked on other posts similar like this one but I'm not able to find the solution.

Here's the method that I invoke which is throwing the error:

```
public static List<UserInformation> GetUsersByUserName(string userName)
        {
            try
            {
                var usersServiceClient = new LDapServicesSoapClient();
                var requestMessage = new LDapUserNameLookupRequest();
                requestMessage.UserName = userName;
                requestMessage.AccessKey = "secretkey";
                var response = usersServiceClient.LDapGetUserByUserName(requestMessage);
                return response.Users.ToList();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException e)
            {
                if (e.InnerException is QuotaExceededException)
                {
                    throw new Exception("We have found many users, please write another filter");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Usually this error is thrown when a service is invoked expecting a response type but responds with another one (HTML in this case). Tipically, if the service is configured for return the right "non-html" response, this error appears when the inner call of the service throws an exception itself, causing a 500 status code described by a 500 error html page. Try to catch the response of the usersServiceClient.LDapGetUserByUserName(requestMessage); get the html and save it in a .html file, then open it and you could get the error of the service (if I've got the point where it is thrown)

Comment: I cannot get that, I'll need to learn how to use fiddler.

Comment: If you can access to LDap server, try to look logs in EventViewer or in the service itself if it have a log system

Answer (score 0):

Adding this configuration to my web.config file did the magic:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LDapServicesSoap" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="address"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LDapServicesSoap"
        contract="LDapServices.LDapServicesSoap" name="LDapServicesSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```